# Problem with non-mounting ZFS-pools at Ubuntu 20.04 boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, mount, grub-efi, zfs

I‘ve got a HP-Notebook which ran out of power, cause someone unplugged the power cable, while the top was closed. So, when the battery got empty, the notebook quitted without someone taking notice of the disaster. Next morning, I reconnected the power and tried to start - and at first I thought, everything is working as usual - but soon I saw, there is a big problem: The system doesn‘t start up correctly any more:

There is a M2-SSD installed as the main (first) memory and an other
SSD (normal type) for backup use and additional purposes.

And, I‘ve got Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (desktop) installed, using zfs-partitions as the place, where / (the main root) and /boot are situated.

When powering up, the notebook tells me

> Boot Device Not Found Please install an operating system on your hard
> disk Hard Disk (3FO)

So, I tried to be clever, and started the notebook using a live-system-stick, using the same Ubuntu type.

When checking the drives and their description by using the GUI gnome-disk-utility (3.36.3)

I can see the M2-SSD description as a 512 GB Disk (type ADATA SX8200PNP), used as /dev/nvme0n1

The M2-type-SSD has got 4 partitions:

1st /dev/nvme0n1p1 is an EFI FAT-32 filesystem, using the startup files for grub (UUID: CE07-F830)

2nd /dev/nvme0n1p2 is a swap-partition (even not really necessary)

3rd /dev/nvme0n1p3 is a zfs-pool („zfs-member“) - if it would mount - the fork /boot in the ubuntu mounting hierarchy. Partition-type: "Solaris Boot", content „Unknown (zfs-member 5000) – not mounted“seems

4th /dev/nvme0n1p4 is also a zfs-pool, and the central root ( / ) in the ubuntu mounting hierarchy; it identifies as partition-type: "Solaris Root" and the rest like the previous partition.

The second physical disk is a conventional (SATA) SSD, type WDC 1 TB-Disk WDS....

It is recognized as /dev/sda and its partitions are regarded as follows:

1st 69 GB FAT(32-bit) partition /dev/sda1, UUID AC33-D0D8 (not used), but mounted by the live-system under /media/ubuntu/AC33-D0D8

2nd another zfs-pool, named backpool (not mounted)

At first, I checked (as root), weather the start-up process uses BIOS or (U)EFI

> [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS

and the result was: UEFI

The hardware booting standard of the notebook is also UEFI

The I checked, if both booting modes would be available

> dmidecode -t0 | grep -Ei "BIOS boot|UEFI"

and the result was

```
BIOS boot specification is supported
UEFI is supported
```

So both starting methods would be available (if necessary).

To complete the information, using

> parted -l

results in (german language based, should be understandable anyway)

> Modell: ATA WDC WDS100T2B0A (scsi) Festplatte  /dev/sda:  1000GB
> Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B Partitionstabelle: gpt
> Disk-Flags:
>
> Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem  Name  Flags
> 1   1049kB  68,7GB  68,7GB  fat32              msftdata
> 2   68,7GB   981GB   913GB   zfs

> Warnung: Der Treiberdeskriptor sagt, dass die physische Blockgröße
> 2048 Bytes ist. Linux sagt, dass es 512 Bytes sind.
> Ignorieren/Ignore/Abbrechen/Cancel? Ignore

> Modell: ADATA SX8200PNP (nvme) Festplatte  /dev/nvme0n1:  512GB
> Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/512B Partitionstabelle: gpt
> Disk-Flags:
>
> Nummer Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem    Name Flags

> 1   1049kB 538MB   537MB   fat32  EFI System Partition  boot, esp
> 2   538MB   2685MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)    swap
> 3   2685MB  4833MB  2147MB  zfs
> 4   4833MB  512GB   507GB   zfs

Using

> blkid

results in

> /dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="CE07-F830" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System
> Partition" PARTUUID="46e5220d-a629-4b26-8450-9be92ddebc44"
> /dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="bpool" UUID="9802228009427858141"
> UUID_SUB="16061671603784305426" TYPE="zfs_member"
> PARTUUID="87a718e6-e031-c141-8914-d43aecf2504b" /dev/nvme0n1p4:
> LABEL="rpool" UUID="3451739961591355705"
> UUID_SUB="6789784670973405573" TYPE="zfs_member"
> PARTUUID="0f41dc6d-1f20-4947-b7e7-49a2c2d81e6f" /dev/sda1:
> UUID="AC33-D0D8" TYPE="vfat"
> PARTUUID="69b0f50a-d658-44d9-b376-964ff8f6b8a5" /dev/sda2:
> LABEL="backpool" UUID="16235635384131684710"
> UUID_SUB="9850795481404374110" TYPE="zfs_member"
> PARTUUID="9c03c38e-6328-4208-8b88-fd55d85c88ab" /dev/sdb1:
> UUID="2023-03-16-15-57-27-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS amd64"
> TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="405a23c7" PTTYPE="dos" PARTUUID="405a23c7-01"

So, I think as a first diagnosis:

1. The notebook (by default) boots UEFI-based (so does the USB-live-system-stick)
2. The information, about how the M2-Disk and its partitioning-scheme is not corrupted (otherwise, I could not see all the details any more)
3. The boot sector could be ok
4. The information, how and where to boot and plug-in the zfs-pools got lost and is somewhat unavailable at startup-time.

Additionally I‘ve got two ideas, about the reason about the mess:

A) Either the fact, that /dev/sda/ is preferred to /dev/nvme0n1 leads to looking up startup files on the wrong drive

or

B) the information how and where to mount got somewhat lost.

When the live-stick-boot is finished, there are no zfs-pools or datasets available.

Using

> zfs list

leads to

> no datasets available

and

> zpool status

results in

> no pools available

and

> df -h -t zfs

tells me

> df: keine Dateisysteme bearbeitet (translated: no datasets in use)

Anyways, the content of the pools isn‘t lost. I tried to mount the pools manually, like (in a terminal and as root):

> mkdir /boot2

> zpool import -f -R /boot2 / backpool

and i can work with the contents.

However, I did not succeed in convincing ubuntu to start up the two zfs-pools (bpool, rpool) and integrating them at boot-time in a running system.

So I need help. Any ideas? Any additional information needed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Learn what an [on-topic question](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) is. Then take a look to [the help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.